# styling ionic tabs items

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-tabs

I'm using **Ionic 4** and using Tabs layout.

I have to design the tabs items like

[image]

For this, the tabs.page.html is like

```
<ion-tabs>

    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="primary">
        ...

        <!-- center button with round border -->
        <ion-tab-button tab="ride" class="tab-btn-ride">
            <ion-icon name="bicycle"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Ride</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        ...

</ion-tabs>
```

To make the button round, here is the css

```
.tab-btn-ride {
  width: 4rem !important;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5pt #ff9823;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  max-width: 5rem;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

This looks fine in the browser (above image) while development. But after generating apk, it looks like the below image in Android device. The upper part is clipped or hidden below the page view.

I tried increasing the z-index value but no luck.

[image]

Comment: May be it's needed image for ride tab

Comment: You mean I should use image in place of icon, text and css?

Comment: try using ion-fab

Comment: ion-fab generates floating button. in my case they are tab buttons

Answer (score 0):

The round image cut because of footer height. So resolved this issues as below

1. Increase footer height
2. Reduced round image size.